# access mySql via multiple ssh in java

Tags: java, mysql, ssh, jsch

I'm new to ssh and I have a question.
I have to connect via ssh to a gateway and within the ssh session I've to ssh to another server.
Only then I can connect to the mySQL server.

1. `ssh <gateway>`
2. `ssh -L3306:db02:3306 username@db02`

Then I can configure Putty and HeidySQL to access the mySQL database.
So far, so good.

But now I want to access the mySQL database via java code.
I googled and found some code to use Jsch.

So, below is the result of the code.
But when I run the code, the session is okay, portforwarding is okay.

But this part is giving me an error:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:"+nLocalPort, strDbUser, strDbPassword);
```

> This is the error: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'dbUser'@'gateway.appl.local' (using password: YES)

It seems like the port forwarding is not done because of the error that it shows to connect to the gateway: 'dbUser'@'**gateway**.appl.local'

After a succesfull port forwarding it should show something like this: `dbUser'@'**db02**.appl.local`

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MySqlConnOverSSH {
    private static void doSshTunnel( String strSshUser, String strSshPassword, String strSshHost, int nSshPort, String strRemoteHost, int nLocalPort, int nRemotePort ) throws JSchException
    {
        final JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession( strSshUser, strSshHost, 22 );
        session.setPassword( strSshPassword );

        final Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put( "StrictHostKeyChecking", "no" );
        session.setConfig( config );
        session.connect();
        session.setPortForwardingL(nLocalPort, strRemoteHost, nRemotePort);
    }

    /**
     * Java Program to connect to remote database through SSH using port forwarding
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            String strSshUser = "sshUserName";                           // SSH loging username
            String strSshPassword = "sshPassWord";               // SSH login password
            String strSshHost = "10.20.0.234";          // hostname or ip or SSH server
            int nSshPort = 22;                                    // remote SSH host port number
            String strRemoteHost = "db02";  // hostname or ip of your database server
            int nLocalPort = 3307;                                // local port number use to bind SSH tunnel
            int nRemotePort = 3306;                               // remote port number of your database
            String strDbUser = "dbUser";                    // database loging username
            String strDbPassword = "dbUserPW";                    // database login password

            MySqlConnOverSSH.doSshTunnel(strSshUser, strSshPassword, strSshHost, nSshPort, strRemoteHost, nLocalPort, nRemotePort);

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:"+nLocalPort, strDbUser, strDbPassword);
            con.close();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't want to do this, it's going to be horribly slow

Comment: What happens if two persons want to do the port forwarding you describe in your second step?

Comment: Guys, I'm totally new to shh.. so, give an alternative how i can accomplish this. I'm thankfull for every little help in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

This will be quite slow, but if you absolutely have to, set up the tunnel across both connections:

```
on your local host: ssh -L3306:localhost:3306 user@host1
on host1:           ssh -L3306:localhost:3306 user@db02
```

Then you should be able to connect to 3306 on your local system and be tunneled through to 3306 on db02.  If `host1` is also running mysql and you don't want to interfere with it, use a different intermediate port, as in

```
on your local host: ssh -L3306:localhost:3316 user@host1
on host1:           ssh -L3316:localhost:3306 user@db02
```

Comment: HI Jim, how should i run these ssh commands in java code ? Or should i do this with Putty and then access the mySql server on db02 via localhost? 
btw: mySql is not running on host1

Comment: Run these in putty to set up the tunnel, then your Java code accesses the DB at localhost:3306.

Comment: Ok.. I will give this a try. Thanks and I will let you know.

Comment: I run those 2 commands and in my Java code i get this error: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'eric'@'localhost' (using password: YES)  
   
This is the java code:  
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:"+nLocalPort, strDbUser, strDbPassword);  
   con.close();

Comment: That message is from the remote MySQL server.  Do you have the correct permissions in the database? To MySQL the login looks like it originates in the server itself, so you need to have permissions for user `eric` on `localhost`.